# Google Play website doesn't show all previously installed apps

Tags: google-play-store

When I browse my app history on the Google Play website(of apps that I have tried out in the past but aren't currently installed on my phone), it only lists them in alphabetic order until about 'L'. Nothing beyond that is shown. Does it have a hard limit on how many previous apps it can show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stops for me as well, so I am lead to believe that it only stores so many in the database.

Looking at it, it seems to be limited to 20 pages (it doesn't even get to 'C' for me).

Comment: I've upvoted your answer, but I don't know if I should mark it as accepted or wait for other replies.

Comment: It depends. Do you only see 20 pages? Does it seem correct? Do what you want.

Comment: You're right..just 20 pages. So this is answered then.

Comment: In my case, the list is not limited to 20 pages. Might be google has fixed the issue. Shows all the apps that are installed from play store as well as system apps.